# Best way to practice bass (drum) technique without a bass drum

Tags: practice, drums, bass-drum

A question to all those who have been or are in my current situation of temporarily not having access to a bass drum to practice on. I do have a pair of sticks and carry a pad to practice my hand technique, but I am clueless as to what is the right way to practice my foot technique when on the go. I have only tried tapping my feet on the ground with the heel firmly planted down to emulate playing heel down. Would this be recommended for extended periods of time (a few months) without reliable access to a bass drum? Would appreciate any other recommendations as well. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use a regular kick drum pedal attached to a Yamaha electronic kit standalone bass drum pad. At least you can practice dynamics on the pedal/kick drum more effectively this way.

You may be able to pick up an old one or create something yourself to emulate this.

Comment: Even a kick pedal with a robust cardboard box on it might do.

Comment: Great suggestion! This might be the best course of action for me, especially considering the fact that it wouldn't be giving my neighbors a reason to object to loud noise etc.